# What are topological grupoids?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading about topological grupoids, and I have understood the definition of a grupoid, that it is some kind of category with the the added condition that every morphism is invertible.

My questions are:

i) Let $G$ be a grupoid, how should I understand the $s,r:Mor(G)\longrightarrow{Ob(G)}$ range and source maps. Are they morphisms in $G$ or where does this maps come from?

ii) What is a topological grupoid (I haven't found some "nice" definition for it) and could anyone give me an example for a topological grupoid and explain its source and range maps?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5):

The source and target maps of a general category $C$ are simply two maps $$\{\mbox{morphisms of }C\}\rightarrow\{\mbox{objects of }C\}$$
For example if $C=\mathbf{Set}$, then $s$ (resp. $t$) sends a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ to its domain $A$ (resp. its codomain $B$). The same is true for a groupoid: $s$ maps a morphism $f:a\rightarrow b$ to the object $a$, while $t$ maps $f$ to $b$.

A topological groupoid is a groupoid where the collections of objects and morphisms are equipped with a topology and all the operations done in a normal category (composition, assign an identity to an object,...) must be continuous.

Specifically, a **topological groupoid** $X$ is two topological spaces $Ob(X),Mor(X)$ together with the following maps

- Two continuous maps $s,t:Mor(X)\rightarrow{Ob}(X)$, called "source" and "target".
- A continuous map $i:Ob(X)\rightarrow Mor(X)$, called "identity".
- A continuous map $\mu:Mor(X)\times_{Ob(X)}Mor(X)\rightarrow Mor(X)$ called "composition". Here $Mor(X)\times_{Ob(X)}Mor(X)$ is the subspace of $Mor(X)\times Mor(X)$ of all pair $(f,g)$ such that $s(f)=t(g)$

We write $1_c:=i(c)$ and $f\circ g:=\mu(f,g)$. We also write $f:c\rightarrow d$ to say that $s(f)=c$ and $t(f)=d$. Then, for every $f:c\rightarrow d$ we require that $$f\circ i_c=i_d\circ f=f$$ and $$f\circ(g\circ h)=(f\circ g)\circ h$$ (for all $f,g,h\in Mor(X)$ such that the previous compositions make sense). Finally, we require that for each $f:c\rightarrow d$ in $Mor(X)$, there is a $(g:d\rightarrow c)\in Mor(X)$ such that $$f\circ g=1_d\qquad g\circ f=1_c$$

Notice that the first two conditions are just the usual conditions for "identity" and "composition" in a general category. The only difference is that these operations must be continuous.

A trivial example of a topological groupoid is the following: Take a topological space $M$ and set $Ob(X)=M$ and $Mor(X)=M\times M=M^2$. Then let

- $s:M\times M\rightarrow M$ be the projection onto the first component (that is, $s(x,y)=x$) and $t:M\times M\rightarrow M$ the other projection $t(x,y)=y$. So the pair $(x,y)$ is the unique morphism $x\rightarrow y$.
- Identity is the diagonal immersion $M\ni x\mapsto (x,x)\in M\times M$
- $Mor(X)\times_{Ob(X)}Mor(X)$ is the subspace of $(M^2)\times(M^2)$ of all pairs $((x,y),(z,x))$ and composition is given by $$((x,y),(z,x))\mapsto(z,y)$$
  I leave to you checking that this is a topological groupoid (that is, all operations I have defined are continuous and satisfy the three conditions given above)

**Edit**

i) I would say that $\mu$ is correct: By definition $\mu$ is defined on the subspace of $M^2\times M^2$ of pair $((x,y),(x',y'))$ such that $x=s(x,y)=t(x',y')=y'$, so $\mu$ is define on the pairs $((x,y),(x',x))$ and $((x,y),(y,z))$ doesn't belong to this space.

I think the problem is with notation: Pairs of composable morphisms (that is, pairs of morphisms $(f:b\rightarrow c,g:a\rightarrow b)$) can be written in two way, either as the ordered pair $$(g,f)$$ so that you can picture them as consecutive arrows $$a\xrightarrow{g}b\xrightarrow{f}c$$ or as the pair $(f,g)$ so that in the composition you write them in the same order $f\circ g$ (that is, "first component $\circ$ second component"). At the end it doesn't change anything, you can define $Mor(C)\times_{Ob(C)}Mor(C)$ as the pair $(f,g)$ having $t(f)=s(g)$ and it would ok (but, of course, you have to stay coherent with your choice for $Mor(C)\times_{Ob(C)}Mor(C)$)

ii) Regarding the question about $G$-principal bundles. You already said it: Objects are principal bundles $(P,\pi,B)$ and morphisms $(P,\pi,B)\rightarrow(Q,\rho,B)$ are continuous, fiber-preserving, $G$-invariant maps $P\rightarrow Q$. Here is your groupoid. The problem of defining $s,t$ still remains because maps a morphism $\phi:(P,\pi,B)\rightarrow(Q,\rho,B)$ could be a also a morphism of $G$-principal bundles $(P,\pi',B)\rightarrow(Q,\rho',B)$ (for $\pi\neq\pi'$ and $\rho\neq\rho'$). So the source of $\phi$ is $(P,\pi,B)$ or $(P,\pi',B)$? The problem is much more general, an alternative way to define a category $C$ is to give to each pair of objects $a,b$ a class of morphisms $Hom(a,b)$ (in particular, a morphisms $f\in Hom(a,b)$ may also be a morphism $f\in Hom(c,d)$, for other objects $c,d$). In this case you can define a different category $C'$ **equivalent** to $C$ with the same objects ($Ob(C')=Ob(C)$, while a morphisms $a\rightarrow b$ in $C'$ is a triple $(f,a,b)$, with $f$ a morphisms $a\rightarrow b$ in $C$. Then $C'$ has well-defined source and target maps: $$s:(f,a,b)\mapsto a,\qquad t:(f,a,b)\mapsto b$$ composable pairs in $C'$ are those in the form $((f,a,b),(g,c,a))$ with composition $(f\circ g,c,b)$. This is the formal way to go, but usually you can just say "Given a morphisms $f:a\rightarrow b$, its source is $a$ and target is $b$" (because by writing $a\rightarrow b$ you specified a source $a$ and a target $b$). As long as it doesn't generate confusion, you're allowed to abuse notation a bit (as long as you make sure that everything fits).

Check, for example, [Definition of category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category) and [Internal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category). Also, notice that in a topological groupoid, objects and morphisms are topological spaces, in particular they are **sets**. I don't think that $G$-principal bundles form a set, but rather a **class**. Maybe you can define a [Grothendieck topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+topology) instead, resulting in a [site](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/site) that is also a normal (that is, non-topological) groupoid.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your reply :)
On the last line you wrote that the multiplication $\mu((x,y),(z,x))=(z,y)$ shouldn't it be $\mu((x,y),(y,z))=(x,z)$ ?

Comment: So suppose that $(P,\pi,B)$ is a principal $G$-bundle over $B$.
The principal $G$-bundles over a given topological space $B$ forms a category where the objects are $(P,\pi,B)$ and morphisms $\sigma:P\longrightarrow{Q}$ are $G$-maps, every principal $G$-bundle morphism is an isomorphism, so this category has an inversion for each morphism.
I can see that this category is a grupoid, I want to give it a topological grupoid structure.
So the objects of this grupoid X are $Ob(X)=B$ and $Mor(X)=P$?
I am really confused on how to define the source, target, inversion and multiplication maps.

Comment: A note on the last part: I always treated principal bundles as nothing more than a normal category, so the idea of introducing a topology (normal, or Grothendieck) is not something I thought of. Perhaps more expert people than me can answer this specific example.