# Concrete examples of internal categories (other than small categories)

Tags: category-theory, big-list

I understand the definition of an [internal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category), but so far I haven't found examples of internal categories (other than categories internal to $\mathrm{Set}$, which are just the small categories) that one could encounter "naturally" in mathematics.
I have only found other abstract concepts related to this one.
**What are some concrete examples that can motivate the study of internal categories?**
In particular, why is it useful to think of operations such as "assigning the domain to a morphism" as being a morphism in a certain category?

---

The only example I've found here is [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4096688/326036), namely that where we consider a topological space $X$ as the set of objects of a category, and $X \times X$ with the product topology as the set of morphisms, with the "obvious" operations.
This is interesting but seems a bit pointless at first sight; for instance, what is the use of thinking of composition as a continuous operation in this example?

Comment: The canonical internal categories are those internal to $\mathbf{Set}$, which are naturally of interest to modelling category theory in set theory.

Topologically enriched internal categories I am told are useful for synthetic homotopy theory and such, although I am (slightly) more familiar with the cooption of this to construct exceptionally nice models for type theory.

Answer (score 5):

This is no means a comprehensive answer, but I can't post a comment because I don't have enough points.

One example that has been very useful for me is that strict monoidal categories are categories internal to monoids.

[This was used by Lack in order to compose props via distributive law.](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/13/9/13-09.pdf)

Also, double categories are categories internal to Cat.

Answer (score 2):

To every group object $G$ (internal group) in a category with finite limits, we can associate an internal category: let $1$ be the object of objects and $G$ be the object of morphisms, and composition is multiplication in $G$.